# python pytest pluggy - pytest_runtest_logfinish AssertionError

Tags: python, pytest

`pytest` is failing with following error.
Might be related to https://github.com/pytest-dev/pluggy package

**Code**   Exception location
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/src/_pytest/terminal.py#L598

**Error:**

```
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 270, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 324, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 349, in pytest_runtestloop
INTERNALERROR>     item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 113, in pytest_runtest_protocol
INTERNALERROR>     ihook.pytest_runtest_logfinish(nodeid=item.nodeid, location=item.location)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/test/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/terminal.py", line 592, in pytest_runtest_logfinish
INTERNALERROR>     assert self._session
INTERNALERROR> AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem refers to the colon (:) used at the end of the code